# CSS hover on li child

Tags: css, hover

I have this CSS Script here

```
#social_side_links li:nth-child(3):hover {

image

}
```

but it does not work....my image does not show up and yes the path is absolutely right...do I need to write this like

```
#social_side_links li:hover nth-child(3) {
```

Comment: my question is am I calling the hover correctly?

Comment: Post the HTML, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/EeHdF/

```
#social_side_links li:nth-child(3):hover {
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

Chaining :nth-child and :hover as you do here should work just fine. If you're using IE6, however, only the last pseudo-class in the chain will be recognized.

I know you feel the image is correct, but try another css definition like border (above) to see if it is an issue with your definition or the selector.